# LINUX + find the root cause for exception - failed to create bus connection: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: linux, rhel, d-bus, systemctl

here is a strange exception for `timedatectl` command , on our RHEL server version 7.6

```
timedatectl set-timezone UTC
Failed to create bus connection: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

based on that exception we found from google searching that dbus service restart maybe can help So we try also to restart the dbus by service as

```
systemctl restar dbus.service
```

but we get

```
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: Resource temporarily unavailable (g-io-error-quark, 27)
```

After some debagging we found that workaround is to kill the `dbus` PID , by `kill -9`

As

```
ps -ef | grep dbus
dbus        775      1  0 May22 ?        00:27:30 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation

kill 775
```

then we try again as

```
timedatectl set-timezone UTC
```

and above was success

so based on our steps and until we found the solution

we want to understand if our workaround is proper solution for – “Failed to create bus connection: Resource temporarily unavailable
“

And why we get the exception about – “Failed to create bus connection: Resource temporarily unavailable” from `timedatectl`

**What is D-Bus?**

D-Bus is a communication system between applications of very diverse origin. With this system we can even call proprietary applications (if they implement D-Bus). It does not play the same role as a library because a library is not an independent program and the library is part of your executable. The D-Bus idea is inspired by the Windows OLE, COM and ActiveX objects. Windows COM objects offer a simple way to call any program from another program, even being able to visually embed one inside another without using the same programming language. D-Bus doesn't go that far but it offers that communication that UNIX lacked.

Comment: To my knowledge, `dbus` has an interface for the RTC, so I can imagine, somehow it claims exclusive access to the RTC, thus `timedatectl` can't access the RTC (which is required at timezone change).

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310). For the record, the other copy is [on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1722868/432690).

Answer (score 0):

The error you are referring to "Resource temporarily unavailable" typically occurs when you hit a global or local resource limit.

IE a `ulimit` or global value in `/sys` or `/proc`.

The most common causes on the command line whilst invoking commands is generally due to hitting a thread limit.

I'd consider checking `ulimit -a` and seeing if these values are high.

**Note**: The task ulimit is for *tasks* not processes, (all threads included) so to get a reliable count you should do something like `$(pgrep -wu your_user | wc -l)`

Comment: In this case I would expect highly threaded commands to fail, not only a simple thing like `timedatectl`. It seems much more likely to me that really the resource, in this case the hardware RTC is blocked somewhere in `dbus`.

Comment: @Philippos Thats unlikely, the error occurs at connection to dbus. Not after inspecting the status of the RTC. Other errors occur with different titles for those kinds of problems. I probed the source code for the 'authority' lines but couldn't find examples of them. EAGAIN Is common in non-block operations too but dbus doens't seem to do that.

Comment: is it possible to capture the error about "ailed to create bus connection: Resource temporarily unavailable" withour restart any systemctl service?